# Optimising a specific type of DB query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a many-to-many relation between two objects: Quotes and Books. A quote can belong to multiple books, but usually only one or two. On the other hand a book usually has multiple quotes attributed to it. I have a SQL query for the quotes which I'd like to turn into a single query for all the books that have at least one of the quotes:

I have done the following for the to change a query from Quotes into the corresponding one for all the Books:

```
def get_books(session, quotes):
        quote_id_query = quotes.from_self(Quote.quote_id)
        book_query = (session.query(Book)
                             .join(Book.quotes)
                             .filter(Book.book_id.in_(quote_id_query))
                             .distinct())
        return book_query
```

This works but it is way to slow for certain quotes queries. If quotes is empty, the corresponding book query is quick, but if the corresponding quote query is non-empty then it may take upwards of 10 seconds(about 1000x what the quotes query takes and even being slower than N+1 queries). I am using a recent version of Postgres. I have indices on my secondary table and my attempts to EXPLAIN ANALYZE the problem have met a plan almost a dozen levels deep. Can anyone help me reduce these queries to sane times?

EDIT: Here are the current model definitions:

```
class Quote(BaseModel):
    quote_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    full_text = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    uses = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    popularity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    books = relationship('Book', secondary='quotebook', back_populates='quotes')

class Book(BaseModel):
    book_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    author = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    genre = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    cost = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    quotes = relationship('Quote', secondary='quotebook', back_populates='books', lazy='joined')

class QuoteBook(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'quotebook'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('book.book_id'), index=True)
    quote_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('quote.quote_id'), index=True)
```

Comment: Can you include your model definition?

Comment: I can do that - but there is nothing out of the ordinary I think. Just a Quote model, a Book model and QuoteBook model.

Comment: Because of your `lazy="joined"`, you're actually joining from `Book` to `Quote` twice. You can also do a join directly from `quote_id_query` instead of using `IN`, which may also improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i think replacing the in will help a lot.

Comment: As pure speculation, eliminating the extra join will help more than removing the `IN`, since the db should be able to optimize that into a join anyway.

Comment: How would you recommend getting rid of the extra join. I can

Comment: Try using `lazy="subquery"` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the subquery joining first then getting rid of the in later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should log, look and post the SQL statement generated for review (set sqlalchemy.engine logger to INFO), but your join(Book.quotes) should already perform an inner join condition so your filter(Book.book_id.in_(quote_id_query)) is extraneous and should be removed.

Depending on the size and definitions of your tables, if the join is expensive, you might also consider testing the performance of an exists clause using filter(Book.quotes. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=has#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.has (quoteid>0)